# Ionic Folder Structure not loading in Browser Dev Tools

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a sample Ionic app and I've structured the app as follows:

```
    |-- www
        |-- index.html
        |-- src
            |-- core.js
            |-- global
                |-- views
                    |-- landing
                        |-- landing.js
                        |-- landing.html
```

For some reason, when I type `ionic serve`, I see **core.js** but I don't see the folder **global** folder. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you included e.g. landing.js in index.html? With "see" you mean Chrome developer tools, right? Chrome is showing you the files it loads, it doesn't scan you file-system (usually).

Comment: Yeah, it took me awhile to figure it out. I had to write a script to manually add the files in each directory to index.html. Had a 'duh" moment!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed the content of ionic.project, then you have to provide `index.html` in the `www` folder.

Comment: index.html is in the `www` folder.